# Text in pdf files is crooked

Tags: windows, pdf, windows-11, microsoft-edge, font-smoothing

The text in pdf files is "crooked" (for lack of a better term, see screenshot below). It get't corrected if the text is selected with the mouse. The problem re-occurs after scrolling.

- I use Edge, but the problem also occurs when using Adobe Reader.
- Deactivating hardware acceleration on Edge did not change anything.
- Firefox does not appear to have that problem
- I have Windows 11

[image: Screenshot of text showing the problem]

Comment: The "text" is actually low quality JPEG images, usually 1 image per page but sometimes more, and what you are seeing is a result of scaling and moving the image without re-rendering the entire page. It is a feature of the way the programs are written. Notice in section 17 where you have highlighted that the line below is actually stretched vertically slightly. The only real solution is to get a PDF that has proper written text in it or use a program with a better image renderer.

Comment: @Mokubai Not sure if I understand you correctly. Is your explanation consistent with the observation that it looks fine in Firefox and that the text looks good after it has been selected?

Comment: Can you link a copy of the PDF for me to check? Some PDFs are actually images with the OCR'ed text behind, the image being the "golden" copy used in case the OCR is wrong, selecting the text may well force the program to re-render that section. I suspect the actual issue is in scrolling and rendering at the same time. You scroll a section, the program starts to render the new area and by the time it has rendered you moved on a pixel or two or the renderer assumes that it was still moving when it wasn't and so you end up with one line stretched and another squashed. Firefox handles it better.

Comment: Can you scroll using the arrow keys or page-up page-down keys rather than the mousewheel? Does that change how often this occurs?

Comment: @Mokubai https://environment.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-11/Proposal%20for%20a%20Regulation%20on%20packaging%20and%20packaging%20waste.pdf

Scrolling with arrow keys is possible but does not appear to change anything.

Comment: Okay, so looking at it it is a proper text PDF which means it is something in Edge/Adobe or your graphics drivers. I do get an amusing effect as it renders new sections in low quality before they get re-rendered in high quality which is where I think your problem is happening. Can you update your graphics drivers at all?

Comment: @Mokubai My graphic drivers are up to date. It's a fairly new system, as well.